# Как быстро найти в какой из непересекающихся интервалов попадает точка?

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Пускай у нас есть набор непересекающихся отрезков на прямой, заданных целочисленными координатами начала и конца. Пускай для определенности левая точка входит в отрезок, а правая - не входит. И таких отрезков много. Они упорядочены по возрастанию, к примеру:

```
[0 2)
[2 4)
[5 6)
[17 19)
[21 30)
[32 90)
[96 124)
[125 900)
```

Мне нужно по заданной координате (к примеру, 25) быстро определить индекс того отрезка, в который она входит (ответ - в 4-й, если считать с нуля), или сказать, что не входит ни в один отрезок (например, координата 20)

я придумал только такой алгоритм:
и левые, и правые координаты я сохраняю в отдельных массивах.

```
L: {0, 2, 5, 17, 21, 32, 96,  125}

R: {2, 4, 6, 19, 30, 90, 124, 900}
```

Когда мне выпадает точка - методом деления пополам массива L - отвечаю, для какого индекса в массива L выполняется условие "это самый младший индекс в массиве, для которого точка больше или равна значению элемента по этому индексу".

Потом делаю похожую операцию в массиве R, определяя "самый старший индекс в массиве, такой, что точка строго меньше значению элемента по этому индексу".

Если определенные при этом индексы в массивах совпали - это ответ в стиле "точка принадлежит такому то отрезку".

Если не совпали - точка вне отрезков.

Покритикуйте?

Comment: Значения только целочисленные от 0 до 1000? Насколько отрезков много, сотня? Если да, то как вариант можно отрезки "растеризовать" на массив из 1000 элементов (каждый элемент - ид отрезка или -1). Время поиска станет линейным.

Comment: Деление на два массива звучит лишним. Ищите сразу по парному массиву Левую точку, а Правую искать не придется - она вот она рядом с Левой лежит.

Comment: У вас упорядоченный массив непересекающихся интервалов, используйте самый обычный двоичный поиск :)

Comment: «Потом делаю похожую операцию в массиве R» вот это лишнее. У вас уже есть индекс. Нужно только проверить что точка попала в отрезок.

Comment: @tym32167 - Вы правы, просто есть ситуации (к примеру - 8 отрезков, а координаты их концов - в пределах 1000), когда двоичный поиск занимает времени больше, чем перебор. Можо было бы положить все точки от 0 до конца диапазона - в словарь, в котром координата это индекс, а значение - номер отрезка или ноль. Но немного неэкономно по памяти...

Comment: добавил вторым ответом, выбирайте что больше нравится )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Накатал на скорую руку обычный двоичный поиск.

Для начала надо как то сравнивать точку и интервал

```
private int Compare(int point, int[] interval)
{
    if (point < interval[0]) return -1;
    if (point >= interval[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Потом реализовать простейший двоичный поиск

```
private int BinarySearch(int[][] data, int point)
{
    var l = 0;
    var r = data.Length - 1;

    while (r >= l)
    {
        var mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
        var midCompare = Compare(point, data[mid]);
        if (midCompare == 0) return mid;
        if (midCompare < 0) r = mid - 1;
        else l = mid + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

ну и проверка

```
var data = new[] {
        new []{0, 2},
        new []{2, 4},
        new []{5, 6},
        new []{17, 19},
        new []{21, 30},
        new []{32, 90},
        new []{96, 124},
        new []{125, 900},
    };

Console.WriteLine(BinarySearch(data, 25));
Console.WriteLine(BinarySearch(data, 20));
```

Вывод

```
4
-1
```

Сильно не дебажил код, но идея думаю ясна.

Answer (score 2):

Поместите все концы всех отрезков в единый массив. В этом массиве выполните обычный двоичный поиск, который возвращает индекс для вставки значения. Для 20 индекс равен 8 (если 20 вставить между элементами с индексами 8 и 9, порядок сохранится). Для 25 индекс равен 9:

> ```
>                              25
>                              |
>                              v
> [0, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 17, 19, 21, 30, 32, 90, 96, 124, 125, 900]
>                          ^
>                          |
>                          20
> ```

Если индекс (*i*) вставки нечётный, то точка попала в отрезок с индексом *(i - 1) / 2*. Иначе точка попала в промежуток между отрезками.

`bsearch(a, x)` возвращает индекс для вставки `x` в массив `a`:

- `0` если `x < a[0]`,
- `len(a)` если `a[len(a) - 1] <= x`,
- иначе `i` такой что `a[i - 1] <= x < a[i]`.

`where(points, x)` возвращает индекс отрезка в который попал `x` если он попал. Если `x` никуда не попал со знаком минус возвращается индекс отрезка следующего за `x`.

```
def bsearch(a, x):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(a) - 1

    if x < a[lo]:
        return 0

    if a[hi] <= x:
        return len(a)

    while lo + 1 < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid

    return hi


def where(points, x):
    i = bsearch(points, x)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        return -(i // 2) - 1
    return i // 2

    
segments = [
    (0, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (5, 6),
    (17, 19),
    (21, 30),
    (32, 90),
    (96, 124),
    (125, 900)
]

points = [p for s in segments for p in s]
for x in (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 899, 900, 901):
    w = where(points, x)
    print(w, end=': ')
    if w < 0:
        i = -w - 1
        if 0 < i:
            print(f'[{segments[i - 1][0]}, {segments[i - 1][1]}) < ', end='')
        print(x, end='')
        if i < len(segments):
            print(f' < [{segments[i][0]}, {segments[i][1]})', end='')
        print()
    else:
        i = w
        print(f'[{segments[i][0]} <= {x} < {segments[i][1]})')
```

Если `x` попал в отрезок печатается в какой отрезок он попал. Иначе печатаются отрезки между которыми он попал:

> ```
> -1: -1 < [0, 2)
> 0: [0 <= 0 < 2)
> 0: [0 <= 1 < 2)
> 1: [2 <= 2 < 4)
> 1: [2 <= 3 < 4)
> -3: [2, 4) < 4 < [5, 6)
> 2: [5 <= 5 < 6)
> -4: [5, 6) < 6 < [17, 19)
> -4: [5, 6) < 7 < [17, 19)
> -4: [5, 6) < 16 < [17, 19)
> 3: [17 <= 17 < 19)
> 3: [17 <= 18 < 19)
> -5: [17, 19) < 19 < [21, 30)
> -5: [17, 19) < 20 < [21, 30)
> 4: [21 <= 21 < 30)
> 4: [21 <= 22 < 30)
> 7: [125 <= 899 < 900)
> -9: [125, 900) < 900
> -9: [125, 900) < 901
> ```

Comment: еще есть варианты, когда число находится в массиве. Тогда четный индекс - число попало, нечетный - не попало

Comment: Двоичный поиск "здорового человека" не обрабатывает случай равенства специально. Кажется что проверка на равенство ускоряет (раньше выходим). На деле замедляет (две проверки на итерацию вместо одной). Кроме того двоичный поиск возвращает точку куда надо вставлять искомое значение. Обнаруженное равенство не означает что эта точка уже найдена. Всегда надо продолжать до тех пор пока индексы `lo` и `hi` не станут соседями.

Comment: Вообще мой комментарий был не про код, а про текст в вашем ответе - что помимо вариантов, когда есть куда встаить искомое число, также это число можно там найти. С другой стороны, я не вижу никаких проблем с дополнительным сравнением (забота о таких вещах кажется мне экономией на спичках), как и не понимаю, что за зверь такой - поиск "здорового человека" - я с таким термином не знаком, сам встречал реализации и так и так.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, двоичный поиск - это общий алгоритм, который к сортированным данным легко применить. Однако, он может оказаться не самым эффективным, если пытаться учитывть какие то конкретные особенности ваших данных и вариантов использования вашего алгоритма.

Например, если у вас кординаты находятся в каком то небольшом интервале (условно, от 0 до 1000), то можно заранее выделить память под массив и получить константный алгоритм, пример

```
var data = new[] {
    new []{0, 2},
    new []{2, 4},
    new []{5, 6},
    new []{17, 19},
    new []{21, 30},
    new []{32, 90},
    new []{96, 124},
    new []{125, 900},
};

var points = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 1000).ToArray(); 
for(int i=0; i<data.Length; i++)
    for (int j = data[i][0]; j < data[i][1]; j++)
        points[j] = i;

Console.WriteLine(points[25]);
Console.WriteLine(points[20]);
```

Выисление индекса в этом случае тривиальное и очень быстрое. Однако, на таких числах (1000 точек) на практике алгоритм покажет прирост скорости если количество вызовов кода будет большим. Условно, если у вас N точек в интервале, подготовка варианта с массивом займет N и поиск будет константой, при этом двоичный поиск будет Log(N), вроде очевидно, что N+1>log(N) (при N=1000 это будет 1001 > 10, то есть бинарный поиск в 10 раз быстрее). Добавим количество запросов сюда, получим

```
N + 1*K = K*Log(N)
```

Чтобы понять, со скольки запросов массив будет обгонять двоичный поиск, решим уравнение

```
K = N / (Log(N) - 1)
```

N=1000, то получаем примерно K=10. Конечно, это очень неточно, прямо скажем, сильно очень не точно, но я надеюсь, идея понятная - количество запорсов должно линейно расти (или быстрее, чем линейно) от количества точек, чтобы алгоритм с массивом оставался эффективным. Вот как выглядит зависимость

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, условно, на массиве из 40000 точек надо выполнить как минимум 3000-4000 тысячи запросов, чтобы оправдать время построения массива перед обычным довичным поиском.

Другой вариант данных - это когда у вас нет четкого интервала всех точек, но у вас много малентких интервальчиков, все точки которых в сумме влезают в интервал, например, тот же 1000. То есть у вас могут быть [0, 5), [5000, 5007), [10000, 100010) и так далее, но в сумме у вас точек все равно не более 1000, условно. Тогда можно от массива перейти к хештаблице (он же словарь). Пример:

Получение значения из словаря

```
private int GetOrDefault(Dictionary<int, int> data, int key, int def)
{
    if (data.ContainsKey(key)) return data[key];
    return def;
}
```

тест

```
var data = new[] {
    new []{0, 2},
    new []{2, 4},
    new []{5, 6},
    new []{17, 19},
    new []{21, 30},
    new []{32, 90},
    new []{96, 124},
    new []{125, 900},
};

var points = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    for (int j = data[i][0]; j < data[i][1]; j++)
        points[j] = i;


Console.WriteLine(GetOrDefault(points, 25, -1));
Console.WriteLine(GetOrDefault(points, 20, -1));
```

Количество ключей в словаре так и останется небольшим, поиск будет что то типа константы (хоть словарь и чутка медленнй доступа к массиву). Ну и рассуждения про массив применимы и здесь.

Comment: Очень крутой ответ, который можно было бы добавить в учебники по информатике! Жалко, что "зеленой галкой" здесь нельзя отметить несколько ответов! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Рад, что понравилось =)